# Is there a way to download multiple PDF's that are linked on a website?

Tags: pdf, web-scraping, automation

I am trying to download a bunch of PDF's from the federal reserve archives but I have to click on a link and then view the PDF before I can download. Is there a way to automate this?

Example: https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/5170#521653 is a link to speeches and then you have to click the title, then view pdf, then the actual download button.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

All of the remote `.pdf` files follow the path format:

`https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/files/docs/historical/frbatl/speeches/guynn_xxxxxxxx.pdf`

where each `x` is a placeholder for a digit.

So, yes, it's very easy to download a bunch of these PDFs in one go using the command-line in *Terminal* or whatever shell program you have access to.

If you're in a *nix-based operating system (including MacOS), that's good because your shell probably already has a command utility called `curl` installed.  Windows may have it too, I'm not sure; I don't use Windows.

If you're using Windows, you'll have to make some tweaks to the code below, because the folder structures and file naming conventions are different, so the first couple of commands won't work.

But, if you're happy to proceed, open up a *Terminal* window, and type in this command to create a new directory in your *Downloads* folder, into which the `.pdf` files will be downloaded:

```
mkdir ~/Downloads/FRASER_PDFs; cd ~/Downloads/FRASER_PDFs
```

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Next, If there's no error, copy-n-paste this long command and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
curl --url \
"https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/files/docs/historical/frbatl/speeches/guynn_{"$(curl \
https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/5170#521653 --silent \
| egrep -io -e '/files/docs/historical/frbatl/speeches/guynn_\d+\.pdf' \
| egrep -o -e '\d+' | tr '\n' ',')"}.pdf" -O --remote-name-all
```

You can see this uses the URL you supplied in your question, from which that command retrieves all the `.pdf` links.  If you need to do the same with other similar pages, provided they all use the same URL format, you can just substitute `5170#521653` with whatever page reference contains another list of `.pdf`s.